# Output loop leveraged shortcode twice on one page

Tags: loop, shortcode

The code below is meant to simply loop through posts, give the opportunity to add html formatting to them, then return them to the shortcode position. I have conditional logic which defines formatting based on the passed in "category"(term). I need to output it twice on the same page, but I only see code that I've added outside of the loop.

```
add_shortcode('my_shortcode','generate_my_shortcode_content');
function generate_my_shortcode_content($atts){
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post-count' => 3,
        'category' => 'default-cat'
    ), $atts );

    $post_count = (int)$a['post-count'];

    $post_category = explode(',', $a['category']);

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my-type',
        'posts_per_page' => $post_count,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'my-taxonomy',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $post_category
            )
        )
    );

    $test = "<h1>";

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($query->have_posts()):while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();

        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
        $post_content = get_the_content($post_id);

        $posts .= $post_id . $post_title . $post_content;
        $test .= "this is a test";

    endwhile;wp_reset_postdata();endif;

    $test .= "</h1>";
    return $posts . $test;
}
```

This function will return `{Post ID}{Post Title}{Post Content}<h1>this is a test</h1>` on the first execution, but will only return `<h1></h1>` on the second. Why is this?

Comment: What do you mean by "second execution"? The second time you refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are doing with your shortcode, but I think you need to run rewind_posts() to move the loop counter back to the beginning for the second "execution." 
Example here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts

further explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729847/wordpress-difference-between-rewind-posts-wp-reset-postdata-and-wp-reset-q

Answer (score 0):

Try not messing with the global `$post` a WP_Query doesn't need to call `the_post()` to loop over the posts.

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ):

    foreach( $query->posts as $post ):

        $post_id = $post->ID
        $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
        $post_content = get_the_content($post_id);

        $posts .= $post_id . $post_title . $post_content;
        $test .= "this is a test";

    endforeach;

endif;
```